# looping through a list of images with specific time interval in vue js

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I'm trying to loop through an array of images that I have on my device , all the images in the loop are displayed fine but I want to only show the first Image in the array when the page loads and after each 4 seconds I want to change the image to the next image in the array and animate the entering and leaving of each image, I tried many things to accomplish this like if statement but I believe that v-for and transition-group is the best way to accomplish this but I still can't do it.
Thanks.

```js
data () {
  return {
    images :["ice.png" , 'g3.png' , 'w3.png']
  }
},
methods : {
   getImageUrl(imageUrl) {
     return require('../assets/Images/' +          imageUrl); 
   }
}
```

```css
    .fade-enter {
        opacity : 0
    }
    .fade-enter-active {
        transition:opacity 1s ease-in-out
    }
    .fade-leave-active {
        opacity: 0;
        transition:opacity 1s ease-in-out
    }
```

```html
<template>
  <div>
    <transition-group name = "fade">
      <div class = "img float-right">
        <img 
         v-for = "image in images"   
         :src = "getImageUrl(image , index)"            :key = "image">
      </div>
    </transition-group>                  
  </div>
</template>
```